# How can I make a grid of 3D obstacles in JAVA?

Tags: java

I want to make a tile grid of 3D obstacles(like buildings in a city). I came up with a 2D array of coordinates in which we can save each building's location on the grid. Each building has a base of 1x1 square and a height 'h'. I want to depict a 3D grid of these buildings but I don't know which JAVA library to use and how to use it.

I already tried depicting a 2D grid using JAVA Graphics(drawRect(),...). In this implementation, as a result, I get a grid of squares with some cells being a color other than the grid's background color showing the obstacles.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // Important to call super class method
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // Clear the board
    g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    // Draw the grid
    int rectWidth = getWidth() / NUM_COLS;
    int rectHeight = rectWidth;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
            int x = j * rectWidth;
            int y = i * rectHeight;
            Color terrainColor = terrainGrid[i][j];
            g.setColor(terrainColor);
            g.fillRect(x, y, rectHeight, rectWidth);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(x, y, rectHeight, rectWidth);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "an actual 3D render"? Because that would be very hard

Comment: I would suggest that this questions is to broad to be answered simply within the confines of SO and that you might need to do some more research into things like [isometric game theory](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+isometric+game&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: “I want to depict a 3D grid of these buildings” —How do you want it depicted?  What do you expect it to look like?  “3D grid” doesn’t adequately describe what you want to see rendered.  That said, you’ll probably have a much easier time of it using JavaFX than Swing, as JavaFX has direct support for 3-D shapes.

Comment: @VGR Something like this picture: https://api.intechopen.com/media/chapter/37778/media/fig9.jpg

Comment: @MadProgrammer You are right, I want something similar to an isometric map but I want to know if it is possible to do it in Java Swing or JavaFX.

Comment: @Rocket147 Yes, it's very possible and if you take the time, you'll probably find a number of ready made solutions or you could just try and see if you can make it work yourself

Comment: @MadProgrammer If you can give me the link to a ready-made solution just to get the idea on how to do it, I will be able to make mine from the scratch. I just want a kick start because I am new to JavaFX and Swing.